# Reversing a String of words with recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to reverse a full string in java

For example, `Good morning` so the output should return `morning good`.

I am tried the below function

```
public static String reverse(String s)
    {
        if (s.isEmpty())
            return s;
        //int n = 0;
        return reverse(s.substring(1)) + s.charAt(0);

    }
```

But the above function is converting `good morning` into `gninrom doog`. My code working on each character, how I make it work on words. Any hint or guide/explanation will be appreciated.

I already been to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723912/reversing-a-string-with-recursion-in-java) question but not solving my problem

Updated:

Trying the below code with the help of @snr answer and @NathanHughes comments

```
public static String reverse(String s)
    {
        int s1 = s.indexOf(" ");


        if (s1 != -1) 
        {
         return reverse(s.substring(s1+1)) + s.substring(0,s1);
        }
        else
        {
            return "-1";
        }
    }
```

But output is

```
-1good
```

Comment: If you knew how to split the string into words, would you be able to solve the problem from there?  Have you looked into how to split a string into words?

Comment: `s.substring(1)` gives you a string with the first character of `s`. This isn't quite what you want.

Comment: @ScottHunter You mean s.split(" "); in my case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reverse words of a Java String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910092/how-to-reverse-words-of-a-java-string)

Comment: So where are your attempts? Besides copying from the linked question?

Comment: Dear @ArvindKumarAvinash it helped but I am trying to solve it with recursion

Comment: Fun fact: breaking a sentence down into words requires full language dictionary. Because of so-called hyphenated compound words, that I even used in writing this very comment!

Comment: @M. Prokhorov is overthinking, assume space separates words. your hint is: use indexOf and substring.

Comment: @NathanHughes, whether or not I'm overthinking depends on how the end result is going to be used, and what the input is. To some extent, reversing a string is as simple as reversing order of its chars, right? Now, armed with that knowledge, can I reverse a string that contains emoji? Let's not forget that SO is not a site that tries to help very specific user to solve very specific problem. We are supposed to also help future users.

Comment: @M. Prokhorov: it seems like a toy problem to practice basic recursion, identifying word boundaries is interesting but doesn't seem directly relevant to my interpretation of the problem.  obviously if we extend this to CJK charsets then identifying word boundaries gets really tough.

Comment: I am just starter of recursion

Comment: I am trying to use indexOf(" ") but its return type is int, I can not recall function with it

Comment: indexOf() returns the beginning index of the substring in the string... or -1 if not found

Comment: Dear all updated my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At first, you need to know where spaces are.

```
public static String reverse(String str) {
   int space = str.indexOf(" ");
   return space == -1 ? str : reverse(str.substring(space + 1)) + " " + str.substring(0, space);
}
```

Comment: Can you please help me with my code where I am going wrong?

Comment: @AHF you need to return `s` instead of `"-1"` which a string literal consisting of two characters which are `"-"` and `"1"`, contiguously in your code. Moreover, you've forgotten to add space.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most efficient way of doing it, but it works:

```
public static String reverse(String s) {
    String[] wordList;
    wordList = s.split(" ");
    String reverseWordList = "";

    for (int i = 1; i <= wordList.length; i++) {
        reverseWordList += wordList[wordList.length - i] + " ";
    }

    reverseWordList = reverseWordList.trim();
    return reverseWordList;
}
```

Comment: The op asked for `recursion`